# Click() в jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Есть такой код

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    grayscale.prepare( $('.disable'));
    grayscale( $('.disable') );
    $('.disable').click(function() {
    grayscale.reset( $(this) );
    }, function() {
    grayscale( $(this) );
    });
```

Вот и `<img src="/img/img_1.png" alt="" class="disable" />`

Суть в том что используя `grayscale.js` делаю все `<img href="path" class="disable" alt="">` черно-белыми и при "клике" он становится цветным, но при клике на несколько элементов они все становятся цветными.

Вопрос в ток как сделать так что бы при клике только один элемент оставался цветным , а остальные становились grayscale.

Вот на такой участок ХТМЛ применяю.

```
                     <li>
                        <div class="personDataCont">
                            <img src="/img/img_1.png" alt=""  class="disable" />
                            <div class="empolyeName">
                                <p class="nameExecutive">Юзер Юзеров</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, пусть и не очень красивый, но зато работающий вариант - http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/b2TSw/. Думаю, что вы сможете довести его до ума сами.

```
$('.personDataCont').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('disable')){
        grayscale($(this));
        if($('.visible').length > 0){
            var visEl = $('.visible');
            grayscale.reset(visEl);
            visEl.removeClass('visible').addClass('disable');
        }
        $(this).removeClass('disable').addClass('visible');
    }
});

grayscale.prepare($('.personDataCont'));
```

Comment: У вас наоборот, делает черно-белым , а остальные цветными остаются.Но и на этом спасибо ) Поковыряю ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $imgs = $('.disable'); //отправим массив картинок в переменную, что бы каждый раз не делать выборку
  grayscale.prepare( $imgs );
  grayscale( $imgs );
  $imgs.click(function() {
    grayscale( $imgs ); //сначала все картинки сделали серыми
    grayscale.reset( $(this) ); //подсветили нужную
  });
});
```

Comment: У меня на массиве объектов все работает (единственное я не grayscale() делал, а простую проверку с .hide()/.show()). Возможно ошибка в чем-то другом. Сложно ответить не видя конкретного кода. Тестовой странички в сети нет?  :) Очень бы помогла в этом случае.

Comment: Выведите дэбаг и посмотрите на результаты. Выполняется ли click на картинках или нет. Пример писал выше:

**$imgs.click(function() { console.log('Click on - ' + $(this)) });**

Comment: Консоль пишет что нету переменной $imgs.

Comment: подразумевалось, что вы замените 

grayscale( $imgs );
grayscale.reset( $(this) );

из вышеприведенного ответа на 

console.log('Click on - ' + $(this))

а остальная конструкция останется неизменной. 
Объявите переменную ( var $imgs = $('.disable');), а после добавляйте debug клика по картинке.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() 
 {
  grayscale.prepare( $('.disable'));
  console.log('Click on - ' + $(this));
 var $imgs = $('.disable');
});`
Написал так,ничего не произошло, проблемка в том что я с Jquery и Javascript не дружу(минус мне)

Comment: Простите, а как вы проверяли в самом начале работоспособность моего кода? полностью скопировали и проверили на страничке или подправили свой код? Попробуйте скопировать и ставить все "как есть" из ответа. Код рабочий и должен отработать и у вас (если название стиля на картинке правильное). Возможно вы перенесли не полностью или с ошибкой код из ответа  и это вызвало ошибку.

Comment: Делал оба варианта ) И ваш и свой правил.

`$(document).ready(function() {
  var $imgs = $('.disable');
  grayscale.prepare( $imgs );
  grayscale( $imgs );
  $imgs.click(function() {
    console.log('Click on - ' + $(this));
  });
  var $imgs = $('.disable');
});`

Вот так должно быть ? Консоль молчит.